# How can I create an array of objects with the index being a string?

Tags: typescript

I wanted to create something like this

For example:

```
      let userTestStatus: { test: string, name: string }[] = [
      { "test": 't', "name": "Available" },
      { "test": 't1', "name": "Ready" },
      { "test": 't2', "name": "Started" }
  ];

  //I want to access the object like the example below
  console.log(userTestStatus['t'].name);
```

But in this way I get undefined. I wanted to access the object like this: userTestStatus['t'].name

Is there anyway of doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are ok with just transforming the object to a new one, as Joseph Wang suggested, what you're looking for might a way to define a getter for any property.

Some javascript implementations used to have a way to do this, but they are non-standard and I believe currently removed.

The only way that I know of to create an object with 'calculated properties' like this is probably the [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

However, that too requires a bunch more plumbing to make it work.

My recommendation would be to try and figure out why you need this, and see if there's other, simpler ways to accomplish this.

The simplest is indeed to just transform this object. This transformation allows you to access your object exactly in the way you want in your example:

```
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  userTestStatus.map( item => [item.key, item] )
);
```